# How to prevent my servlet from being called from some other website

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, authentication, servlets

Okay so I have a simple servlet like this.

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println(req.getParameter("name"));

    }
}
```

Lets say it gets triggered when I use this URL /simple_servlet.do

How do I ensure that this servlet works only if it is called from my website and not from some other website. In other words is there some request parameter (which cannot be spoofed) that lets me know.

Comment: As I understand you want to Look for Authorization of the servlets for incomming request?

Comment: I guess no one else can call just your servlet, just like that from another context, unless it is registered in your web.xml

Comment: Yes it is registered in my web.xml so they can call from another context. @pratikch Yes how do I go about doing that?

Comment: is your site and your servlet hosted under same domain ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I can think of, is that you to generate a Token on the server from your website (for example an MD5 on the JSESSIONID), and pass that token back to your servlet. Only your website knows the token, other website cannot steal cookies (including the JSESSIONID) and compute the token from outside. This should be safe also from [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks.

Comment: I think this is right approach, there need to a token sharing between website and java app. And this token should be generated on each page load on website and communicated to java app(through server to server communication)

Comment: you can generate every time, but it will make things much harder to handle. if you just make `token=hash(sessionid)` other application need a plugin or something installed in the broser to take the session id cookie from another tab or another window of the brower, to calculate the token; so it's pretty hard anyway, even if the token is fixed and chained on the sessionid. btw, if you can handle one-time tokens, even better (but page refresh won't work, history.back() may have troubles, and other things)

Comment: what I would suggest is not to make post request to java app from website html page. Website post should go into website itself(may be php) and website has to be make a post request to java app(server side http) with secret token param. This will avoid the need for key generation on each load. and also solve all back button cache problems.

Comment: In token solution use hmac or keyed md5, with timestamping because if page is vuln to xss you can obtain session id and easily calculate valid token.

Comment: @fatfredyy can you tell me how can I obtain some a cookie belonging to site X from site Y? I knew it's impossible. But I am keen to learn this, if it is true. --update: oh yes, with xss: it is true, it's possible (but it would be better to handle XSS which would be quite a big hole).

Comment: Cross site scripting... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29  vector is similar to CSRF

Comment: yes, I did not read properly. But if the site is vulnerable to XSS, then you could probably do session spoofing and enter the website as authenticated user... then you could possibly load any page linking to the servlet and there you go: you could also get the token with hmac and time window... so I'm not sure that encrypting the token really adds anything to security. You need to exploit a bigger vulnerability (XSS) to exploit another one (XSRF).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the session between client and server to detect whether the first time.

```
if (req.getSession(false) == null) { // false = do not create a session
   // No user session
}
```

Comment: if a session is active, other web sites can forge requests to your web site (and the browser will also send the cookie!). So... no, it doesn't work this way. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery.

Comment: some sites implement also the "remember me" feature, in which the session gets created from a persistent cookie, so basically the session is always active. But the problem is there also for 30minutes sessions, even though the vulnerability is limited to the period when the user is logged in. But imagine sites like online trading, which people keep open all the day watching the stocks change...

Comment: The answer from @LuigiR.Viggiano, maybe with a sequence token, is nice to prevent stealing sessions. HTTPS or SSL/TLS would be the better solution, but here is no answer. In fact the question is not clear, and could be answered with 42.

Comment: I don't think that having a *sequence* token adds anything to security compared to an hash token (or just a random token). BTW, most of the websites around are vulnerable to XSRF. On a company I worked for, I had to demonstrate I could change the language of their webapp to arabic just when the user was visiting my blog, before they took the problem seriously. And yes, it was a POST request; with javascript you can do post requests as well as GET.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can prevent by the following.

1. Use `POST` method since more difficult to hack ; [Diff GET vs POST](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post)
2. Ignore GET method which can be sent directly if type URL in browser
3. Check with authentication username,password before process the request
4. Consider writing an authorization `Filter`

Comment: here is how you do a cross site post request without user iteraction: https://gist.github.com/4450591 if the session is active, you pass thru the filter. (3 may work, you need ssl: sending pass via non-ssl is not very wise, and you cannot use `<a href` links with the password encoded and POST method; so it impose also certain limits)

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano you are correct. https is better way but post with some authentication might work. Even if we generate token that must be encrypted.