# Secure servlets from request the outside of domain

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0

How to secure servlet from request outside from page.

At the moment, i can send request from any devices. But i want to get request only from my page or domain.

I will very grafetul for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent my servlet from being called from some other website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152014/how-to-prevent-my-servlet-from-being-called-from-some-other-website)

Comment: *But i want to get request only from my page or domain* - could you elaborate? Currently this is *unclear*